# How can add the custom data in Analytics Revenue stats? Any hook or example

Tags: woocommerce, hook, woocommerce-rest-api

Which hooks can add data to existing reports in woocommerce API?
I want to Extend the Analytics Revenue Stats. Like the Total Orders, Total sales I want to add New Section in API in which I want to show total orders from facebook, twitter, website etc.

I want this in wp-json/wc-analytics/reports/revenue/stats API.
Can you please help me with this?

Please let me know hook for this or one example.
Thanks